# Is it possible to create ksql table from ksql stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm a new bee to ksql. I'm just playing with read kafka topics to streams and it works great.

Also, trying to create a table from kafka topic and failed. Realized that I need to have a key set in kafka topic which is considered as primary key in ksql table.
So I tried creating table from stream instead, but failed too.
Query/Script:

```
CREATE TABLE DETAILS_TABLE AS SELECT SEQ, Server1, ServerId, NumberUri, SERVERID2, SERVER2 FROM details_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTES);
Invalid result type. Your SELECT query produces a STREAM. Please use CREATE STREAM AS SELECT statement instead.
```

Can someone explain if its possible or not? If yes, wher am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If you want the query result to be a TABLE, you need to specify an aggregation query.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I tied this: CREATE TABLE DETAILS_TABLE AS SELECT SEQ, Server1, ServerId, NumberUri, SERVERID2, SERVER2, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM details_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTES) GROUP BY SEQ; the error is: Group by elements should match the SELECT expressions.

Comment: I could succed with CREATE TABLE DETAILS_TABLE AS SELECT SEQ, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM details_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTES) GROUP BY SEQ; But the problem is i need other parameters/colums too. How do i proceed further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Matthias says, you need to specify a (valid) aggregate query.

So this would work:

```
CREATE TABLE DETAILS_TABLE AS \
SELECT SEQ, Server1, ServerId, NumberUri, SERVERID2, SERVER2, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL \
FROM details_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTES) \
GROUP BY SEQ, Server1, ServerId, NumberUri, SERVERID2, SERVER2;
```

Just as any SQL dialect, if you are doing an aggregation, you have to `GROUP BY` *all* of the fields, otherwise it makes no syntactical sense.

Comment: We did, but couldn't pull off. The stream is able to read data from kafak-topic but the table isn't able to. Could read only 2 entries somehow. We are in a hurry to test our POC, so moved out and worked around.

Comment: IS this this the only document https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/tutorials/basics-docker.html to get more info? Can I get much organized doc explains 1)how long does a stream/table persist? 2) How to synchronize between two kafka_topics to use joins? and so on. Thanks.

Comment: is this still the case? or is there an option of a stream.ToTable feature we have available in KSQL?