# KSQL create table with multi-column aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

So essentially I'd like to group by two columns, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT a, b, SUM(a)
FROM whatever
GROUP BY a, b
```

`whatever` is a stream in Kafka format. When I issue the command, ksql returns:

```
Key format does not support schema.
format: KAFKA
schema: Persistence{columns=[`a` STRING KEY, `b` STRING KEY], features=[]}
reason: The 'KAFKA' format only supports a single field. Got: [`a` STRING KEY, `b` STRING KEY]
Caused by: The 'KAFKA' format only supports a single field. Got: [`DEVICE`
    a KEY, `b` STRING KEY]
```

The problem is that the Kafka format does not support multi-column keys. Is there a way to workaround this, e. g. creating an artificial key in this table? I did not manage to do this.

I saw someone posted a similiar question and the answer seemed to work. I suggest that's because of the format. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193239/9632703

The documentation mentions that multi-column aggregations might not work, though also saying that ksql does a background workaround to make it work. Unfortunately ksql only returns the given error message. https://www.confluent.de/blog/ksqldb-0-10-updates-key-columns/#multi-column-aggregations

The funny part is that omitting the first line `CREATE TABLE foo AS` works. So if some data comes in, the aggregation works. But that's not persistent, of course. If nothing else works, I would also be fine with having a table without a primary key defined, if possible in ksql, since I could still identify the data with {a, b} in my application.

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this if you upgrade to ksqlDB 0.15. This version [introduced multi-key support](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksqldb-0-15-reads-more-message-keys-supports-more-data-types/). You'll need to use a `KEY_FORMAT` that supports it.

```sql
ksql> CREATE TABLE FOO AS SELECT A, B, SUM(C) FROM TEST_STREAM GROUP BY A,B;

 Message
-----------------------------------
 Created query with ID CTAS_FOO_53
-----------------------------------
ksql> DESCRIBE FOO;

Name                 : FOO
 Field      | Type
---------------------------------------------
 A          | BIGINT           (primary key)
 B          | VARCHAR(STRING)  (primary key)
 KSQL_COL_0 | DOUBLE
---------------------------------------------
For runtime statistics and query details run: DESCRIBE EXTENDED <Stream,Table>;

ksql> SELECT * FROM FOO EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 5;
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|A                          |B                          |KSQL_COL_0                 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|220071000                  |AIS                        |0.4                        |
|257838000                  |AIS                        |6.2                        |
|538007854                  |AIS                        |22.700000000000003         |
|257487000                  |AIS                        |2.4                        |
|257601800                  |AIS                        |5.8999999999999995         |
Limit Reached
Query terminated
```

Comment: I will look into it in the next days. Thanks Robin. In the meantime, I've managed to create said table by changing the FORMAT to DELIMITED.

Comment: @robin i still get the error with version 0.15 my key format is KAFKA.

Comment: @kailashyogeshwar please open a new question with full details & steps to reproduce.

Comment: As in use proper KEY_FORMAT  when creating `TEST_STREAM`

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, what is the proper key format? I dont understand this one. You could maybe show how you create the stream so we can see what you do with the key format there.